# Can ajaxSetup.success callback prevent ajax.complete callback from being called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

In `$.ajaxSetup.success` I want a general piece of code to check something and then the `$.ajax.complete` callback should not be called. Is this possible? Preferably by doing something in the `$.ajaxSetup.success` callback and not in every `$.ajax.complete` callback.

`event.stopImmediatePropagation` might work, but I don't know how to access `event` from `success`.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    success : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('this will happen');
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    complete: function () {
        alert('this shouldn\'t happen');
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4L4z3oo/1/

Comment: No, `complete` will always be fired. If you need this behaviour you would need to change the logic flow.

Comment: The complete will not be called if we cause an exception to occur in the success handler. i.e throw "The complete shouldn't be called." This is more like a hack.

Comment: Thanks, throwing an exception is a great solution in my case. If you want you can submit it as an answer.